# Recursive algorithm for all k-way partitions of a list

Tags: python, recursion, data-partitioning

I am writing a function that should output all k-way partitions of a list A.
This problem is clearly recursive, and the implementation should be straightforward:

```
def gen_partition_k_group( A, k):
    #
    if len(A) == 0 :
        # EDITED FOLLOWING SUGGESTION
        yield [ [] for _ in xrange(k) ]
    #
    else :
        # all k-partitions of the list of size N-1
        for ss in gen_partition_k_group(A[:-1], k) :
            assert( sum( len(gg) for gg in ss ) == len(A) -1 )
            for ii in xrange(k) :
                tt = list(ss)
                print tt
                tt[ ii ].append( A[ -1 ] )
                print tt
                assert( sum( len(gg) for gg in tt ) == len(A) )
                yield tt

A = range(3)
k = 2
[ xx for xx in gen_partition_k_group( A, k) ]
```

Output

> AssertionError:
>
> [[], []]
>
> [[0], [0]]

I don't understand the output. It should be `[[0], []]` instead of `[[0], [0]]`. What am I missing?

NB: I know how to write a different function without `append` which outputs the correct result. [Iterator over all partitions into k groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353280/iterator-over-all-partitions-into-k-groups) (first answer)

What I don't understand is the behaviour of this particular function.

Comment: You know `[ [] ] * k` for nonzero `k` creates `k` copies of the that identical list, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was the line `tt = list(ss)` which is only making shallow copies of the list. Using `tt = copy.deepcopy(ss)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is probably that `[ [] ] * k` doesn't do what you think it does.  That doesn't make `k` empty lists, it makes one new empty list and `k` references to it.  For example:

```
>>> [[]]*3
[[], [], []]
>>> a = [[]]*3
>>> a
[[], [], []]
>>> a[0].append(1)
>>> a
[[1], [1], [1]]
>>> id(a[0]), id(a[1]), id(a[2])
(25245744, 25245744, 25245744)
>>> a[0] is a[1]
True
>>> a[0] is a[2]
True
```

To make multiple new lists, you could do something like

```
>>> a = [[] for _ in xrange(3)]
>>> a
[[], [], []]
>>> id(a[0]), id(a[1]), id(a[2])
(41563560, 41564064, 41563056)
```

I don't think this by itself will fix your program -- I still get an `assert` tripping -- but it should help.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference about this `[ [] ] * k ` notation? I couldn't find any.