# Get all possible combinations between two lists, including multiple connections

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics

With

```
import itertools
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [1,2,3,4]

x = itertools.product(l1, l2)
print(list(x))
```

I get the 16 possible individual combinations of the lists l1 and l2, `[(1,1), (1,2), ... ]` etc. Is there a way to also get combinations that 'connect' the lists in multiple ways? For example, I could have the following combinations `[(1,1), (2,3)]`, `[(1,3), (2,4), (3,2)]`, and `[(1,2), (2,4), (3,3), (4, 1)]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean 'connect' the lists in multiple ways? From your examples I can't make out what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the problem as placing `l1` balls, into `l2` bins. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66251103/827519) on how to generate all those placements.

Because in your example, there are placements where some of the balls are absent from any bin, we can handle that by introducing an additional bin which we designate to be the trash bin (in other words, balls which end up in this bin, will be considered absent).

Comment: This sounds like it could be the way to go, I think I'm just bad at explaining things. The way I'm thinking of it is two graphs with 4 nodes; the problem then becomes: what are all the possible combinations of nodes that connect the two graphs, only using each node once or not at all?

Comment: Sure, you can also view the problem like that, in which case you are counting [bipartite graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). The solution above is equivalent and should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
from itertools import permutations
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [1,2,3,4]

for i in l1:
    a= permutations(l2,i)
    for m in list(a):
        print(m)
```